# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'quantity') - Angular 12

Tags: undefined, angular12

I have been facing this problem for quite some time now. When I try to add an item to my cart I get this error : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'quantity').

Here is my cart service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Cart } from '../models/cart';
import { Item } from '../models/item';
import {Product} from '../models/product';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CartService {

  cart:Cart=new Cart();
  tva=environment.tva/100;
  cart$=new Subject<Cart>();

  constructor() { }

  emitCart(){
    this.cart$.next(this.cart)
  }

  addToCart(product:Product){
    const item=this.cart.items.find(item=>item.product._id === product._id);

    if(item){
      item.quantity++;
    }else{
      const item=new Item();
      item.product=product;
      item.quantity=1;
      this.cart.items.push(item);
    }
    this.updateCart();
  }

  updateCart(){

    this.cart.items.forEach(item=>{
      this.cart.resume.quantity+=item.quantity;
      this.cart.resume.costHT+=item.quantity*item.product.price;
      this.cart.resume.costTaxe+=this.cart.resume.costHT*this.tva;
      this.cart.resume.costTTC+=this.cart.resume.costHT*(1+this.tva);
    })
    this.emitCart();
  }

  removeOne(product:Product){

  }

  removeMany(product:Product){

  }
}
```

This is my header where a number should be added next to the shopping bag icon when I click on the add to cart icon :

[image]

This is my header component logic :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from "../../../services/auth.service";
import {CartService} from '../../../services/cart.service';
import {Cart} from '../../../models/cart';

@Component({
  selector: 'node-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  isAuth;
  resume:{quantity:number,costHT:number, costTaxe,costTTC:number};
  constructor(private authService:AuthService,private cartService:CartService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.cartService.cart$.subscribe(
      (cart:Cart)=>{
        this.resume=cart.resume;
        console.log(cart.resume);
      },
      (err)=>{
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    )

    this.authService.isAuth$.subscribe(
      (bool:boolean)=>{
          this.isAuth=bool
      }
    )
  }

  logout(){
    this.authService.logout();
  }

}
```

And finally this is the html template of the header just in case :

```
<!-- header start -->
<header>
  <!-- header top start -->
  <div class="header-top theme1 bg-dark py-15">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-7 order-last order-md-first">
                  <div class="static-info text-center text-md-left">
                      <p class="text-white">Join our showroom and get <span class="theme-color">10 % off</span> ! Coupon code : <span class="theme-color">Jstore2021</span></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-5">
                  <nav class="navbar-top pb-2 pb-md-0 position-relative">
                      <ul class="d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-end align-items-center">
                          <li>
                              <a href="#" id="dropdown1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Setting <i class="ion ion-ios-arrow-down"></i></a>
                              <ul class="topnav-submenu dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown1">
                                  <li><a href="#">My account</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Checkout</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Sign out</a></li>
                              </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                              <a href="#" id="dropdown2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">USD $ <i class="ion ion-ios-arrow-down"></i> </a>

                          </li>
                          <li class="english">
                              <a href="#" id="dropdown3" class="pr-0" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                  <img src="assets/img/logo/us-flag.jpg" alt="us flag"> English
                                  <i class="ion ion-ios-arrow-down"></i>
                              </a>

                          </li>
                      </ul>
                  </nav>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <!-- header top end -->
  <!-- header-middle satrt -->
  <div class="header-middle pt-20">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-2 order-first">
                  <div class="logo text-center text-sm-left mb-30 mb-sm-0">
                      <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/logo/logo-dark.jpg" alt="logo"></a>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-5 col-xl-4">
                  <!-- search-form end -->
                  <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-sm-end">
                      <div class="media static-media mr-50 d-none d-lg-flex">
                          <img class="mr-3 align-self-center" src="assets/img/icon/1.png" alt="icon">
                          <div class="media-body">
                              <div class="phone">
                                  <span class="text-muted">Call us:</span>
                              </div>
                              <div class="phone">
                                  <a href="tel:(+33)752152560" class="text-dark">(+33)752152560</a>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- static-media end -->
                      <div class="cart-block-links theme1">
                          <ul class="d-flex">

                              <li class="mr-0 cart-block position-relative" >
                                  <a class="offcanvas-toggle" routerLink="/cart">
                                      <span class="position-relative">
                                          <i class="icon-bag"></i>
                                          <span class="badge cbdg1" *ngIf="resume">{{resume.quantity}}</span>
                                      </span>
                                      <span class="cart-total position-relative" *ngIf="resume">{{resume.costTTC/100|currency:'EUR'}}</span>
                                  </a>
                              </li>
                              <!-- cart block end -->
                          </ul>
                      </div>
                      <div class="mobile-menu-toggle theme1 d-lg-none">
                          <a href="#offcanvas-mobile-menu" class="offcanvas-toggle">
                              <svg viewbox="0 0 800 600">
                                  <path
                                      d="M300,220 C300,220 520,220 540,220 C740,220 640,540 520,420 C440,340 300,200 300,200"
                                      id="top"></path>
                                  <path d="M300,320 L540,320" id="middle"></path>
                                  <path
                                      d="M300,210 C300,210 520,210 540,210 C740,210 640,530 520,410 C440,330 300,190 300,190"
                                      id="bottom" transform="translate(480, 320) scale(1, -1) translate(-480, -318)">
                                  </path>
                              </svg>
                          </a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-xl-6 order-lg-first">
                  <div class="search-form pt-30 pt-lg-0">

                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <!-- header-middle end -->

  <!-- header bottom start -->
  <!-- header bottom start -->
  <nav class="header-bottom theme1 d-none d-lg-block">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
              <div class="col-lg-10 offset-lg-2 d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center position-relative">

                  <ul class="main-menu d-flex">

                      <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/shop">Shop</a></li>

                    <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/add-product">Add product</a></li>

                    <li routerLinkActive="active" ><a routerLink="/signin" *ngIf="!isAuth">Login</a></li>
                    <li routerLinkActive="active" ><a  routerLink="/signup" *ngIf="!isAuth">Register</a></li>


                    <li routerLinkActive="active"  style="color: black;cursor: pointer;" *ngIf="isAuth" (click)="logout()"><a >Logout</a></li>

                  </ul>

              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- header bottom end -->
</header>
```

Sorry I forgot to post the cart class and template so here they are :

```
import {Item} from '../models/item';

    export class Cart {
    
      items:Item[]=[];
      resume:{quantity:number,costHT:number, costTaxe:number,costTTC:number};
    
    }
```

And the item class :

```
import { Product } from "./product";

export class Item {
  product:Product;
  quantity:number;
}
```

Comment: And the error stems from this line : this.cart.resume.quantity+=item.quantity;

Comment: I added the cart class as well as the item class

Comment: I changed the const into a var but it made no difference. Also I used a console.log(this.cart.items) before the  this.cart.items.forEach(item=>{  and I got the object on the console

Comment: I am convinced that I have to initialize resume differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do was add this line as the first line of the `updateCart()` function:

```
resume={quantity=0,costHT=0, costTaxe=0,costTTC=0};
```